# Communication between fragment and dialog in MVVM

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-mvvm

I have multiple fields which need to be filled via custom input/picker dialog fragment, however i'm not sure how to share data between different fragments.

I'm using navigation component with single activity, multiple fragment and navigation is done using actions. For dialog i use global action, since it's used by different screens, so i can navigate to them from any screen. Once i navigate to my input dialog, insert value and click ok, how i notify previous, "host", fragment about new value and update corresponding field ?

I was thinking about holding dialog's view model inside the "host" fragment and observe it's input field, but in this case i would have a view with multiple view models. Since my custom dialog is used in different screen, i don't know haw i could share view model with it.

Comment: Did you try to share your `ViewModel` inside fragments? I'm not sure if it's possible for dialogues, but I know, that you could get the `ViewModel` reference from your Activity and use it inside fragments.

Comment: @BlindKai I could, theoretically, share a view model between two fragments using activity scope. My problem is, however, that i have one common dialog fragment used in different screens, and every screen has it's own view model so i don't which one should be used inside the dialog. Maybe i could pass to the dialog the viewmodel it has to use ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible or kind of good practice, but if you could pass the reference to the ViewModel you could use different ViewModels to perform the same logic.